# Should Random Forest in R take far longer to run with floats vs integers?

Tags: r, floating-point, integer, random-forest

I have a dataset that I am running a Random Forest routine on in R (using caret).  The raw data (all integers) finishes pretty rapidly; if I normalize so that the values are all floats (between 0 and 1, e.g. 0.988), the routine takes forever (so long that it's still running, in fact, after 20 days).  Does this make sense to anyone?